# Django: using data from entries for many views functions

Tags: django, get

I'm new in Django and now I'm working on my first project.

My home.html file includes form (bootstrap class) with contains entries to fill with data.
These data are integer type.

In views, in function home, where this home.html file is used ,
data from entries are taken by 'get' method and used for calculations and results are displaying in labels in mentioned form.

My question is how can I use these data from entries or results of calculations or both of them by another function in views called some_view with generates PDF file using ReportsLab.

Thanks

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
       body { margin: 40px }

        .my-container {
        border: 1px solid green}

        .my-row {
        border: 2px solid blue}

        .my-col {
        border: 2px solid red}
        btn-primary { margin-left: 50px}

        .align-right {

        text-align: center;
        border: 0;
      }

    </style>
</head>
<body>




<div class="container my-container">
    <form method="get">
          <div class= "row my-row">
              <div class="col-3 my-col">

                          <input type="text" placeholder="0" name="li200" size="1" />

              </div>
              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary"> {% if liczba %}
                           {{ liczba }}

                           {% endif %}

                       </span></h3>
              </div>

              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary"> {% if ls %}
                           {{ ls }}

                           {% endif %}

                       </span></h3>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class= "row my-row">
              <div class="col-3 my-col">

                          <input type="text" placeholder="0" name="li100" size="1" />

              </div>
              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary"> {% if liczba1 %}
                           {{ liczba1 }}

                           {% endif %}

                       </span></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary"> {% if ls1 %}
                           {{ ls1 }}

                           {% endif %}

                       </span></h3>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class= "row my-row">
              <div class="col-3 my-col">

                          <input type="text" placeholder="0" name="li50" size="1" />

              </div>
              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary"> {% if liczba3 %}
                           {{ liczba3 }}

                           {% endif %}
                       </span></h3>

              </div>
              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary" name="superowo"> {% if ls3 %}
                           {{ ls3 }}

                           {% endif %}

                       </span></h3>
              </div>
          </div>
                  <div class= "row my-row">
              <div class="col-3 my-col">



              </div>
              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary"> {% if suma %}
                           {{ suma }}

                           {% endif %}
                       </span></h3>

              </div>
          </div>

              <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Click"  name="print_btn">
              <a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" href="{% url 'some_view'%}" >Do PDF</a>
           <div class="align-right">

      </div>

    </form>


   </div>



<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

views.py

```
import reportlab
import io
from django.http import FileResponse
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
#==================================
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import slownie



def home (request):
    ls=''
    ls1=''
    ls3=''
    liczba= request.GET.get("li200")
    liczba1=request.GET.get("li100")
    liczba3=request.GET.get("li50")
    if liczba and liczba.isdigit():
        liczba=int(liczba)*200
        ls=slownie.slownie(int(liczba))
    if liczba1 and liczba1.isdigit():
        liczba1=int(liczba1)*100
        ls1=slownie.slownie(int(liczba1))
    if liczba3 and liczba3.isdigit():
        liczba3=int(liczba3)*50
        ls3=slownie.slownie(int(liczba3))
    suma=0
    if liczba1 and liczba and liczba3:
        suma=int(liczba)+int(liczba1)+int(liczba3)
    return render(request, 'home.html',{'liczba':liczba,'liczba1':liczba1,'liczba3':liczba3,
                                        'suma':suma,
                                        'ls':ls,
                                        'ls1':ls1,
                                        'ls3':ls3})


def some_view(request):

    
    ls = ''
    ls1 = ''
    ls3 = ''
    liczba = request.GET.get("li200")
    liczba1 = request.GET.get("li100")
    liczba3 = request.GET.get("li50")
    if liczba and liczba.isdigit():
        liczba = int(liczba) * 200
        ls = slownie.slownie(int(liczba))
    if liczba1 and liczba1.isdigit():
        liczba1 = int(liczba1) * 100
        ls1 = slownie.slownie(int(liczba1))
    if liczba3 and liczba3.isdigit():
        liczba3 = int(liczba3) * 50
        ls3 = slownie.slownie(int(liczba3))
    suma = 0


       # Create a file-like buffer to receive PDF data.
    buffer = io.BytesIO()

    # Create the PDF object, using the buffer as its "file."
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)

    # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
    # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
    p.drawString(100, 100, ls3)

    # Close the PDF object cleanly, and we're done.
    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    # FileResponse sets the Content-Disposition header so that browsers
    # present the option to save the file.
    buffer.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buffer , as_attachment=True, filename='hello.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add like this

urls.py

```
urlpatterns [
   path('', some_view, name="some_view")
]
```

your templates

```
<form action="{% url 'some_view' %}" method="GET">
   ...
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpfull but I want to use two submit buttons to this form.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpfull but I want to use two submit buttons to this form, first to take data to view.home, make calculations and display it on the site and second button which can take  the same data and take them to view.some_view. When I use code from above these data are taken only to view.some_view. Any idea how can I set buttons actions as I mentioned. Thanks